# Puppet - Dependencies are not working

Tags: elasticsearch, puppet, kibana, elastic-stack

I've been working on a small module which uses the a pre-made kibana puppet module (EDIT: 'lesaux/kibana4'), and also contains a simple exec which installs the shield plugin for kibana. (Sidenote: For this example I am also installing java8 from another module included in my manifest)

My problem is that the exec keeps running before kibana is actually installed. I want kibana to install first, and then the exec. So I added a 'require' as shown below, and also added a chain to ensure the exec happened after.

```
class test_kibana {

  class { '::kibana4':
     package_ensure             => '4.4.0-linux-x64',
     package_provider           => 'archive',
     config                     => {
       'server.host'            => 'localhost',
       'elasticsearch.url'      => 'http://localhost:9200',
       'elasticsearch.username' => 'testUserName',
       'elasticsearch.password' => 'testPassword',
       'shield.encryptionKey'   => 'testencryptionkey',
     }
  } ->

   exec { 'install kibana shield plugin':
     require                    => Class['::kibana4'],
     path                       => '/opt/kibana4/bin',
     command                    => 'kibana plugin --install kibana/shield/latest',
   }

}
```

The require and the chain doesn't seem to work. Therefore when the exec tries to run it does not know what the command means and fail because kibana does not exist yet.

Why does puppet not install these in the order I require?

Here is my output:

```
==> nat: Notice: Scope(Archive::Download[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz]): No checksum for this archive
==> nat: Notice: Compiled catalog for nat.test.com in environment production in 2.58 seconds
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[preferences]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/File[/tmp/java.preseed]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}fa13124e9e801dd42c91fa94ef7f1c1e'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/File[/tmp/jce]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/File[/tmp/jce/local_policy.jar]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}dabfcb23d7bf9bf5a201c3f6ea9bfb2c'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/File[/tmp/jce/US_export_policy.jar]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}ef6e8eae7d1876d7f05d765d2c2e0529'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::User/Group[kibana4]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::User/User[kibana4]/ensure: created
==> nat: Error: Could not find command 'kibana'
==> nat: Error: /Stage[main]/Smart_monitoring_kibana/Exec[install kibana shield plugin]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command 'kibana'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/Apt::Setting[conf-update-stamp]/File[/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp]/content: content changed '{md5}b9de0ac9e2c9854b1bb213e362dc4e41' to '{md5}0962d70c4ec78bbfa6f3544ae0c41974'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/Apt::Ppa[ppa:webupd8team/java]/Exec[add-apt-repository-ppa:webupd8team/java]/returns: executed successfully
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/Exec[apt-update]/returns: executed successfully
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/Package[oracle-java8-installer]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/File[/etc/profile.d/set_java_home.sh]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}717258a243a8addc2506097f12cd611f'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/test_java8/Exec[install-jce]/returns: executed successfully
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Install/Archive[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64]/Archive::Download[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz]/Exec[download archive kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz and check sum]/returns: executed successfully
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Install/Archive[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64]/Archive::Extract[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64]/Exec[kibana-4.4.0-linux-x64 unpack]/returns: executed successfully
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Install/Exec[chown_kibana_directory]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Install/File[/opt/kibana4]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Config/File[kibana-config-file]/content: content changed '{md5}dacdab7bddd2bcede2cc7cd8c6948307' to '{md5}7c24ae699bfbfbb5314ce01bdcdc3b6d'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Config/File[kibana-config-file]/mode: mode changed '0644' to '0755'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Config/File[/var/run/kibana.pid]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Config/File[/var/log/kibana]/ensure: created
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Service/File[/etc/init.d/kibana4]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}0c5c726cdabb5355276abc6394a868a7'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Service/File[/etc/default/kibana4]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}57b82a4af4f8872bfbc6488b0a85c652'
==> nat: Notice: /Stage[main]/Kibana4::Service/Service[kibana4]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
==> nat: Notice: Applied catalog in 644.11 seconds
```

EDIT: I have discovered that the lesaux/kibana module has been updated recently, and now it lets you install plugins as part of the install. (Therefore I no longer need to use this exec function. Issue resolved!)

Comment: is it lesaux-kibana4 you're using?

Comment: Yes its lesaux-kibana4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [containment](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_containment.html) problem.

Classes serve as containers for all the resources they declare directly.  If you declare a relationship with a class, that implies the same relationship with all those resources.

Classes are not resources, however, and classes *do not* automatically serve as containers for the other classes they declare.  There are very good reasons for this, but they are not really relevant here.  The upshot for you is that you have no relationship between the `Exec` and classes `kibana4::install`, `kibana4::exec`, and `kibana4::service`.  Puppet is not constrained to sync the `Exec` after those three.

It is common (but by no means universal) that you do want a class to contain some or all of the other classes it declares.  For that, there is the `contain` function / statement (since Puppet 3.4).  If you add

```
contain 'kibana4::install'
contain 'kibana4::exec'
contain 'kibana4::service'
```

at the *end* of the body of class `Kibana4`, then you will get the containment semantics you are looking for.

If you are stuck with Puppet older than v3.4 (current is 4.4; latest in the v3 tree is v3.8) then there are other ways to ensure proper containment, which you can read about in the manual section I linked.

Comment: Thanks for replying. To make sure I am implementing this correctly:
the contain lines - should they be at the end of my class { '::kibana4': } block? I have placed them right after I close my config section of this class - however when I boot up the vagrant box with this manifest I get a 'Syntax Error at 'contain'.

Comment: @CameronMcAuley, no, they go at the end of the *definition* of class kibana4: `class kibana4 (...) { ... contain 'kibana4::service' }`.  That is, in the same scope where you declare the internal classes `kibana4::service`, *etc*..  I do recommend that you read the manual section I linked, as it provides a lot more detail about the problem and solution.

Comment: Thanks for the manual you linked - this was not something I was aware of before, and this will really assist me in future as this sort of issues crops up quite a lot for me.

I tried placing the contains (kibana4::install, kibana4::exec, kibana4::service) in the location you suggest, however now when I boot the vagrant box the parameters within the ::kibana4 internal class are now not recognised - 'Invalid parameter: 'package_ensure'

Comment: @CameronMcAuley, I had supposed, perhaps incorrectly, that it was class `kibana4` that in fact declares classes `kibana4::install` and friends.  That would be conventional, and if it were not the case then I don't see why you expected the relationship you declared to have the effect you expected it to have.  I had guessed, apparently correctly, that you use resource-like declarations for those classes.  In that case, the `contains` statements need to go *at the end* of that class, as I said, *after* all the (other) class declarations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by class kibana4 - my module starts with class test_kibana and has an internal class ::kibana4 block. When contains are placed at end of ::kibana4 block, I get the Syntax errors and when contains are placed at the end of test_kibana block the internal parameters in ::kibana4 block become invalid. Apologies, i'm not following where exactly I need to place these - you may need to spell it out further as I've tried placing them at the end of both classes!

Comment: @CameronMcAuley, the code you have presented is a *definition* of class `test_kibana`.  That class definition includes a *declaration* of class `kibana4` (== `::kibana4`).  The `contains` statements don't go anywhere in that code.  They go in the *definition* of class `kibana4`.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't have a definition of class kibana4. Where should this take place? The same init.pp file?

kibana4::service,exec and install are all spawned from having the ::kibana4 declaration - I dont have any other code elsewhere that mentions these. The code I have provided is all the code I have in regards to kibana, and the code I have provided is usage of the lesaux/kibana module which I have included in my Puppetfile.

Comment: @CameronMcAuley, you *do* have a definition of class `kibana`, otherwise Puppet would not accept declarations of that class, and it clearly does accept them.  Look for the definition in its third-party module -- probably somewhere like `kibana4/manifests/init.pp`, relative to a directory in your module path.